# Updating multiple documents in mongoose at once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have an array of User documents each user has followers attribute which is a number, I just want to increment this attribute by 1 and then update all those user documents in the DB at once.

#### More details:

In the request I have an array of user ids, I query with those ids to get an array of user documents.

```
const users = await User.find({"_id": {$in: req.body.ids}});
```

each user document has an attribute called followers which is a number.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // other attributes...........,

  followers: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});
```

I want to increment the number of followers in each user in the users array and update the DB at once without sending a request to update each user separately, Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share more details? Please show the documents and expected output

Answer (score 3):

You can use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and run [`updateMany`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany):

```
await User.updateMany({"_id": {$in: req.body.ids}}, { $inc: { followers: 1 } });
```