# UpdateMany mongodb documents with value from document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose with node.js to connect to my MongoDB.  I'm trying to update a bunch of documents at one time using a value calculated from a value already in each document.

My documents look like this:

```
[{
    _id: 'ad07f',
    enabled: true,
    priority: 1,
    more: "more data"
},{
    _id: '9da0f',
    enabled: false,
    priority: 6,
    more: "more data"
},{
    _id: '35fas',
    enabled: true,
    priority: 3,
    more: "more data"
},{
    _id: '5f3ax',
    enabled: true,
    priority: 11,
    more: "more data"
}]
```

I need to update all documents matching a filter. `"enabled":true`.

I need all of these documents to have the priority value increase by 1.  This means I need to look at the value of the document field, calculate a new value, and update the new value.  The calculation is absolutely trivial.

Is there an efficient way to do this?  As is, I'm looking at having to do a `.find({ enabled: true }` then after all data has returned, parse through that with a `forEach` Loop, and then turn around and do individual updates back to the MongoDB for each document.  That seems *terribly* inefficient.

A similar question ([Update multiple elements with different value in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854721/update-multiple-elements-with-different-value-in-mongoose)) was previously asked and the answer was basically to run a forLoop and individually update them.  Perhaps things have changed in the 7 years since that answer?

Comment: "The calculation is absolutely trivial." does it mean that you exactly need to increment the value or there is some other formula? Is this what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60712117/updating-multiple-documents-in-mongoose-at-once/60712397#60712397 ?

Comment: I actually just need to increment the value... but it could be a variable amount of incrementing.  (ie: I might want the option to increment by 5 or something...).  Finding how to increment by '1' would solve the problem, though.

Comment: @mickl - thanks for the help.  Pointing to the $inc did the trick.   It did result in an additional question, however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530436/updatemany-in-mongodb-running-twice-with-inc