# UpdateMany in MongoDB running twice with $inc

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Thanks to the help received in my previous question ([UpdateMany mongodb documents with value from document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530102/updatemany-mongodb-documents-with-value-from-document)), I have learned about incrementing using updateMany.  I wrote the following code:

```
ageAllCameraPriorities = async (req, res) => {
    await Camera.updateMany({ enabled: true }, { $inc: { processingPriority: 1 } }, (err, dbResp) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: "Status 400, unable to age camera priorities" + err })
        }
        if (!dbResp.n) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `No enabled cameras found to age` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: dbResp })
    })

        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

The intention of this code is to run through a mongoDB database that looks like this:

```
[{
    _id: 'ad07f',
    enabled: true,
    priority: 1,
    more: "more data"
},{
    _id: '9da0f',
    enabled: false,
    priority: 6,
    more: "more data"
},{
    _id: '35fas',
    enabled: true,
    priority: 3,
    more: "more data"
},{
    _id: '5f3ax',
    enabled: true,
    priority: 11,
    more: "more data"
}]
```

... and increase each enabled document's "priority" field by 1.

The above code, however, increases the value by 2.

Further, if I change to `$inc: { priority: 3 }` the value increases by 6.  It seems to me that something is likely running twice.  But I'm hitting the endpoint directly with postman and the above code is the entirety of my function.  Where is the second increment coming from?

EDIT:
It's clear the second running is happening during this line:
`return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: dbResp })`
Because I can pull everything out other than that line and it will increment by 2.  If I remove that line, it will only increment by 1. (but the API endpoint never returns anything... so that's not good)

Comment: Try removing the `.catch`

Comment: Are you using async and callback styles at the same time?

Comment: @D.SM ... Yes?   I have to admit, I simply took this format from a tutorial.   What are you suggesting gets changed here? (and/or what should I look up to investigate it myself?)

Comment: The two are mutually exclusive which might explain your behavior. Pick one style.

Comment: @Joe - Removing the catch AND removing the catch did the trick (doing just one of the two still results in a double-update).  I'm unsure why.  Can you explain (and/or point me to where I can learn?)

Comment: The double update happens because when you used both a callback `(err, dbResp) =>` and a promise `.catch(`, so the `updateMany` was executed for each.  I learned about that from the Mongoose docs, but I can't seem to find the link right now.

Comment: It was the `catch` for me. So mixing `(err, doc) =>` and using `.catch` and presumably `.then`  (?) causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

Per comments on the original question, I was able to solve this by removing the `.catch` and the `await`.

```
ageAllCameraPriorities = async (req, res) => {
    Camera.updateMany(  { enabled: true },
        { $inc: { processingPriority: req.params.amount } },
        {},
        (err, dbResp) => {
        if (err) {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ success: false, error: "Status 400, unable to age camera priorities" + err })
        }
        if (!dbResp.n) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error:'No enabled cameras found to age' })
        }
            return res
                .status(200)
                .json({ success: true, data: dbResp })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was just curious to know if this is better.

```
ageAllCameraPriorities = async (req, res) => {
    await Camera.updateMany(
         { enabled: true },
         { $inc: { processingPriority: 1 } }
     ).then((dbResp) => {
        if (!dbResp.n) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `No enabled cameras found to age` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: dbResp })
    }).catch(err => 
       console.log(err);
       return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: "Status 400, unable to age camera priorities" + err });)
}
```