# MongoDb $inc auto increase by twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my code, I have to push some value in the reported array of collections of activity doc. so i use this code

```
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const logData = {
            'reportedBy': body.reportedBy,
            'reportedAt': new Date().toISOString(),
            'reportReason': body.reportReason
        }
        await model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: body.id },
            {
                $addToSet: { 'reported.log': [logData] },
                $inc: {
                    'reported.count': 1
                }
            },
            { new: true }, (err, activity) => {
                createError(err, reject);
                resolve(activity);
            });
    });
}
```

After successfully submit it show me count increase by 1 but in MongoDB, it shows a count 2 can any please guide me about what I miss in the above code.

Comment: @turivishal No this is not my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using async & callback styles which makes the operation execute twice. Pick one style.

See also [UpdateMany in MongoDB running twice with $inc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530436/updatemany-in-mongodb-running-twice-with-inc)

Comment: yes when I was removed resolve reject then my problem solve. Thank you for your update.